# Autofac not resolving constructor parameter for WebAPI2 controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac, autofac-configuration

I'm trying to use Autofac for DI container for an Asp.Net MVCApplication with WebApi2 and OWIN. My global.asax.cs has nothing in the `Application_Start()`. My startup.cs has the following Configuration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    DependencyInjectionConfig.Configure(app);

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

And DependencyInjectionConfig.Configure is:

```
public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration(); //this means webapi controllers don't use DI container
    //var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration; //this makes MVC view controllers fail to do anything


    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    //MVC and WebAPI Controllers
    builder.RegisterControllers(assm);
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(assm);
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    //Model Binders
    builder.RegisterModelBinders(assm);
    builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

    //Modules
    builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

    //MVC Views
    builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

    //MVC and WebAPI Filters

    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
    builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

    //Finally, Any custom registrations
    RegisterComponents(builder, assm);
    /* My items show in the builder as expected at this point */

    //build the container
    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    //Special OWIN bits
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacMvc();
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

My problem is that Autofac does not seem do any parameter resolution regardless of if I use `var config = new HttpConfiguration();` or `var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;`. bonus, if I use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` MVC controllers for views completely fails.

The ApiController is pretty straight-forward:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
     private IMesageHandler MessageHandler {get; set;}
     public MessagesController(IMessageHandler messageHandler)
     {
         this.MessageHandler = messageHandler;
     }
     [HttpGet]
     public string Get()
     {
         return "Hello World";
     }
}
```

The exception is that it can't find a parameterless constructor (because the Autofac container appears to be napping).

Comment: What does the constructor look like, and are the parameter types registered with the container?

Comment: Added the ApiController per your comment. Also, the `RegisterComponents(builder, assm);` call is where all my types get registered and they do appear when I QuickWatch the builder.

Comment: Okay then... huh.  I have no idea.  Maybe turn on tracing in Owin for additional diagnostic information?